# Confusion in eloquent javascript power recursion sample

Tags: javascript, recursion

this recursion code is from the book of eloquent javascript

```
function power(base, exponent) {
  if (exponent == 0) {
    return 1;
  }
  else {
    return base * power(base, exponent - 1);
  }
}

console.log(power(2, 3));
```

obviously the exponent is decreased until it reached 0, if it is not zero, it adds power call on the stack, if it is zero, I start to see the return value of 1 then 2 then 4 then 8. But how did base got multiplied by exponent, how did base see the exponent value? it's on else and on power call?

Comment: `power(2, 3)` is `2 * power(2, 2)` is `2 * 2 * power(2, 1)` is `2 * 2 * 2 * power(2, 0)` is `2 * 2 * 2 * 1` because `power(2, 0)` returns `1`.

Comment: You could step through in a debugger.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth yes I did look at it many times but somehow I am still confused

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *But how did base got multiplied by exponent*

It doesn't multiply by the `exponent`.

The `exponent` is being used as a counter to end the recursive cycle once it's been reduced to `0`. The `base` is instead being multiplied by itself an `exponent` number of times.

This is supported by each call to `power()` returning either `1` or the value of `base`. In the latter case, `power()` is called again to get `1` or another copy of `base` to multiply by. And, this repeats until it does finally return `1` as the final multiplier.

```
            power(2, 3) ==
        2 * power(2, 2) == // base * ...
    2 * 2 * power(2, 1) == // base * (base * ...)
2 * 2 * 2 * power(2, 0) == // base * (base * (base * ...))
2 * 2 * 2 * 1              // base * (base * (base * (1)))
```

---

The same steps could also be defined with a loop, though using `1` as the initial value rather then at the end:

```
function power(base, exponent) {
    var result = 1;

    while (exponent) {
        result *= base;
        exponent--;
    }

    return result;
}

console.log(power(2, 3)); // 1 * base * base * base == 1 * 2 * 2 * 2 == 8
```

Answer (score 1):

I find it easy to understand recursive procedures by looking at their base case first, then building up from there – here's the function we're studying...

```
function power(base, exponent) {
  if (exponent == 0) {
    return 1;
  }
  else {
    return base * power(base, exponent - 1);
  }
}
```

So here, the base case is `exponent == 0`. We'll keep `2` as the input for `base`:

```
power(2, 0) => 1
```

Well that was really easy! All we had to do was evaluate an `if` statement and we arrived at our answer. Looking ahead, we see that `power` arrives at its base case by subtracting 1 from the exponent (`exponent - 1`), we'll reverse this to get our next input – so instead of `power(2, 0)` we will do `power(2, 1)`

```
power(2, 1) => 2 * power(2, 0)
            => but wait! don't re-evaluate power(2,0)! we already know that answer from above
            => 2 * 1
            => 2
```

Ok, we'll keep doing the same thing by incrementing exponent by 1 each time. But be careful not to do unnecessary work – if we've already evaluated one of the expressions earlier, just replace that expression with it's evaluated value

```
power(2,2) => 2 * power(2, 1)
           => we already know power(2,1) == 2 ...
           => 2 * 2
           => 4

power(2,3) => 2 * power(2,2)
           => we already know power(2,2) == 4, etc
           => 2 * 4
           => 8

power(2,4) => 2 * power(2,3)
           => 2 * 8
           => 16

power(2,5) => 2 * power(2,4)
           => 2 * 16
           => 32
```

Now we can easily see a pattern and how the recursive procedure works in general

Answer (score 0):

What you have to notice is that the power function 
returns 1 when exponent is 0 and
return base * power() on another case.

Pay attention to power function

In the following code

```
power(base, exponent - 1);
```

you have to appreciate some things

1) If exponent is 1 the function power returns 1 so in here

```
return base * power(base, exponent - 1);
```

Whether base is 2

```
return 2 * 1
```

The function power is returning 2, so in the next step

```
return base * power(base, exponent - 1);
```

means

```
return 2 * 2;
```

which is 4, that means that function power is returning 4

I think you can catch up from here.

Let me know if you understood :)